# Maintaining Data Type in Colaboratory

Tags: python, pdf, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to use PyPDF2 to read a pdf document and output a plain text string. However, when I upload my pdf file to colaboratory using the code:

```
uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
  print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(
  name=fn, length=len(uploaded[fn])))
```

it automatically coverts it to a str type rather than keeping it as an encoded string. This gives an error with PyPDF.PdfFileReader() but if you print the string it still has all the encoded characters:

> gsutilCheatSheet.pdf => %PDF-1.5
>   %����
>   1 0 obj
>   <>/Metadata 117 0 R/ViewerPreferences 118 0 R>>
>   endobj

etc.

Is there any way to keep the imported document in there original encoded format or is there another way to remove the encoding once it is already a str?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to wrap your uploaded file in an `io.BytesIO`.

Here's a complete example showing how to open an uploaded PDF using PyPDF2 --
https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=1XlmXcp4xnrUGMUArevxiGNlrbMOMECO1

The key bit is:

`pdf = PdfFileReader(io.BytesIO(uploaded['abc123.pdf']))`